# Signal handling in C++ (using instance variable inside method)

Tags: c++, variables, static, signals

I'm not very skilled in C++, so I find this tricky.

I have a class which looks pretty similar to this one : [Is it possible to use signal inside a C++ class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343219/is-it-possible-to-use-signal-inside-a-c-class)., but inside the signal handling method I have to work with an instance variable.

The first thing I tried was to set the variable static, but it didn't help.
What should i do?
Thanks Hynek

Comment: Could you post what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with an instance variable, then you'll need a class instance, since you cant access instance variables from a static method. Your next question will be how to get the class instance, for which there are a few options. You can either make a global variable, which is usually frowned upon, or you could consider making a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). The approach used in option 2 of the accepted answer to the question you referenced is similar to a singleton, so that could also be an option.

Perhaps this would be clearer if you reviewed static methods and attributes. Bruce Eckel's [Thinking in C++](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html) is an excellent free online c++ book that should help.