# Interruption handling with non-static member function

Tags: c++, interruption

I am trying to do interruption handling with a member function from a class.

The code is

```
signal(SIGABRT, socketServer.signalHandler);
```

where the definition of `signalHandler` is

```
public:
void SocketServer::signalHandler(int sig)
{
  logger.info("Receive SIG"+to_string(sig)+" Stopping server now...");
  stop();
}
```

When I compile the code, I got an error says

```
main.cpp:32:32: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
  signal(SIGABRT, socketServer.signalHandler);
```

I am trying to capture `SIGABRT` using this `signalHandler` function and to clean up and stop the `socketServer` instance. I guess I can use global variable and a global function to do the job, but any thoughts about doing this with a member function?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/343219/1340631

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can **not** do this.

The reason is that all *member* functions have an "implied/hidden" `this` pointer argument.  If we "flattened" out your handler definition to produce the C equivalent, it would look like:

```
void SocketServer::signalHandler(SocketServer *this,int sig);
```

The `signal` function [in C] knows nothing of this [pun intended].  If it compiled, the handler would be called with `sig` going into the `this` argument and *not* the `sig` argument.

So, you really must do:

```
SocketServer my_global_server;

void
my_handler(int sig)
{

    my_global_server.signalHandler(sig);
}

int
main(void)
{

    signal(SIGABRT,my_handler);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Actually, the above is *quite* dangerous because `my_global_server` may be in an indeterminate state when the signal handler is called, causing UB.  Also, when in a signal handler, there are a limited number of things you are permitted to do.  For example, *no* heap manipulations are permitted.

Here is a better way to implement this:

```
volatile int signal_flag;

SocketServer my_global_server;

void
my_handler(int sig)
{

    signal_flag = sig;
}

int
main(void)
{

    signal(SIGABRT,my_handler);

    while (! signal_flag) {
        ...
    }

    my_global_server.signalHandler(signal_flag);

    return 0;
}
```