# how to add signal handler as method

Tags: c++

## compile

```
# g++ -rdynamic ./test_stacktrace.cpp -o test_stacktrace
./test_stacktrace.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
./test_stacktrace.cpp:63:25: error: invalid use of non-static member function
  signal(SIGSEGV, b.trace);
```

## code

```
/*
 *  g++ -rdynamic ./test_stacktrace.cpp -o test_stacktrace
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Backtrace {
    public:
        Backtrace();
        void trace(int sig);
};

Backtrace::Backtrace(){}

void Backtrace::trace(int sig){
    void *trace[10];
    char **messages = (char **)NULL;
    int i, trace_size = 0;
    
    trace_size = backtrace(trace, 10);
    messages = backtrace_symbols(trace, trace_size);
    
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: signal %d:\n", sig);
    for(i=1; i<trace_size; ++i){
        fprintf(stderr, "#%d %s\n", i, messages[i]);
    }
    
    exit(1);
}

void baz(){
    int *foo = (int*)-1;
    printf("%d\n", *foo);
}

void bar() { baz(); }
void foo() { bar(); }


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Backtrace b;
    
    signal(SIGSEGV, b.trace);
    foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a global instance of `Backtrace`, you can use it in a plain function, or a lambda expression coercible to the proper type:

```
Backtrace b;

void bTrace(int s) { b.trace(s); }

int main() {
    signal(SIGSEGV, &bTrace);
    signal(SIGKILL, [](int s){ b.trace(s); });
}
```

Comment: `Backtrace b;
void bTrace(int sig){
 b.trace(int sig);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
 signal(SIGSEGV, &bTrace);
 
 foo();
}`

Comment: returns this error `./test_stacktrace.cpp: In function ‘void bTrace(int)’:
./test_stacktrace.cpp:38:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
  b.trace(int sig);
`

Comment: Yes, I've named the argument in lambda but forgot to in global function. See my edited post.

Answer (score 4):

You cant add a member function, there is no way for the `signal` function to bind your object `b`. The function pointer must follow the format:

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
```

Yours is of type::

```
void (Backtrace::*)(int);
```

You will need a either:

1. A global function and a global instance of the class `Backtrace` to add as a signal handler.
2. A static member function and static instance of the class `Backtrace`.

Similar examples [can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343219/is-it-possible-to-use-signal-inside-a-c-class)

However, it doesn't look like your example actually requires a class. You have no member variables. You can use `trace` as a free function to achieve what you want.

Comment: @clarkk yes, the answer lists 2. Links another answer which has a similar 2.

Comment: @clarkk On second look, you don't actually seem to need a class, just make it a free function.